# Proof that there is a unique solution to $Ax=b$ implies rank = $n$ of a $m \times n$ matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am confused in some part of the proof. Let $A =[\bar{a_1} \bar{a_2}\dots\bar{a_n}]$. Suppose, rank($A$) < $n$ then there is a $k$ such that 
$$a_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\alpha_{i} \bar{a_i}$$

Now suppose $(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is a solution. Then we can generate another solution vector where the first $k-1$ terms are $(x_i + \alpha_i x_{k})$ where $i=1,2,\dots,k-1$, the $k$-th term is $0$ and the rest of the terms are as it is. Now, if $x_k$ is non-zero I am getting two different solution vectors, thus getting contradiction, but if $x_k$ is zero in the original solution we get the same vector by our construction process. So, how to get a contradiction ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear equations given by $Ax = b$ have a solution if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A|b) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090742/linear-equations-given-by-ax-b-have-a-solution-if-and-only-if-operatorname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a flaw in the proof, as you have found.
Instead, you can get another solution vector using that $Ay=b$ where
$y_i=x_i+\alpha_i$ for $1\le i\le k-1$,
 $y_k=x_k-1$, and $y_i=x_i$ for $k+1\le i \le n$.

Comment: understood the solution.

Comment: but, is there any way that my soln can be modified to be correct.

Comment: I didn't see an easy way to do that (other than what I did) since, for example, it's possible that $x_i=0$ for $1\le i\le k$.  It's good that you realized that there was a problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

I) If $ \vec{b} = \vec{0} $, then $ \vec{x_{0}} = \vec{0} $ is a solution. Suppose $rank\ A \lt n $, then exists non-trivial linear combination of its columns $ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}x_i\vec{a_i} = \vec{0} = \vec{b}$, therefore $ \vec{x} $ is non-trivial solution and you have two solutions.

II) If  $ \vec{b} \ne \vec{0} $ then the unique solution $ \vec{x} $ you have is non-trivial. Choose $ x_i \ne 0 $ and apply your method to it. (Almost your method actually, you should use the linear combination of all columns)

Comment: i could not understand the 2nd part. What happens if I choose $x_i \neq 0$ from the original soln, but $a_i$ can't be expressed as a linear combination of others. In a dependent set it need not be true that "any" vector can be expressed as a linear combination others. Am I correct ?

Comment: @prasenjit No. If the vectors $ {\vec{a_1}, \vec{a_2}, \dots, \vec{a_n}} $ are linearly dependent, then ANY of them can be expressed as a linear combination of the others: $ \vec{a_m} = \sum\limits_{k \ne m}{\alpha_k\vec{a_k}} $

Comment: your statement is wrong. Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467940/a-basic-doubt-on-linear-dependence-of-vectors

Comment: Sure it is.. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Row reduce $A$.  Picture this in your head.  $A$ can't have more independent columns than rows since it's reduced row form has a maximum of $n$ pivot columns, and if it had less, then there would be a zero row and thus a free variable.